# im trying to find the gap between 2 numbers

Tags: vb.net

I'm having trouble finding the gap between 2 numbers for a parking charge. I tried this:

```
'time for entry
Dim entered As String = txtHourEnter.Text + ":" + txtMinEnter.Text
Dim time As DateTime
Dim display As String = "Invalid entry"
If DateTime.TryParse(entered, time) Then
    display = time.ToString("h:mm tt")
End If
lblTimeIn.Text = display

'time for exited 
Dim exited As String = txtHourExit.Text + ":" + txtMinExit.Text
Dim out As DateTime
Dim display2 As String = "invalid entry"
If DateTime.TryParse(exited, out) Then
    display2 = out.ToString("h:mm tt")
End If
lblTimeOut.Text = display2

'parking time
Dim parkingtime As String = (display - display2)
lblParkingTime.Text = parkingtime
```

But I get this error:

> The OP forgot to include the error message. How embarrassing for them :(

Comment: Why do you think that subtracting a `String` from a `String` should do anything useful? If you want the period between two points in time then use two points in time, i.e. the `DateTime` values. That will give you a `TimeSpan`, i.e. a time period, which you can then compare to other time periods to determine how much they have to pay for parking. DO NOT use `Strings` to represent anything that is not text expect where you have to, e.g. for display. DO NOT perform calculations on text, as you were already told in your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

The code was trying to subtract the strings, instead of the timestamps. You need to get actual datetime values and subtract those.

```
Dim hourEnter As Integer = Int32.Parse(txtHourEnter.Text)
Dim minuteEnter As Integer = Int32.Parse(txtMinEnter.Text)
Dim hourExit As Integer = Int32.Parse(txtHourExit.Text)
Dim minuteExit As Integer = Int32.Parse(txtMinExit.Text)

Dim timeEnter As DateTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(hourEnter).AddMinutes(minuteEnter)
Dim timeExit As DateTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(hourExit).AddMinutes(minuteExit)

Dim parkingTime As TimeSpan = timeExit - timeEnter

lblTimeIn.Text = timeEnter.ToString("h:mm tt")
lblTimeOut.Text = timeExit.ToString("h:mm tt")
lblParkingTime.Text = parkingTime.ToString("h:mm")
```

Comment: lblParkingTime.Text = parkingTime.("h:mm") have identifier expected error

Comment: lblParkingTime.Text = parkingTime.ToString("h:mm") error message: Input string was not in a correct format.